# How to find a lost TActionList

Tags: delphi, tactionlist

My ActionList object has disappeared from my screen.

My Touch Screen went bonkers while I had my `TActionList` selected.  It has sent my ActionList off to somewhere outside the bounds of the screen.

Unlike true visual controls, there is no property in the Object Inspector to set position.

How can I get the ActionList object back into view?

Comment: Two options. 1. Use your revision control system to revert to a previous version. 2. Edit the .dfm file and set the Left/Top properties for the action list to bring it back into view.

Comment: For newer versions (works in 10.3 but not in 7): Select the control in the structure view and do a copy and paste. When pasted controls are moved to the edge of the visible part of the form if past the edges to the right and bottom (doesn't work if the control is up and left of the visible area).

Comment: Open the form in the IDE - you need to see the form, not the code. Press ALT+F12. Now you'll see the dfm content. Search for the ActionList component. Manually set Left and Top to 5. Press ALT+F12 again. Done.

Comment: @ralfiii Make that an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the form in the IDE - you need to see the form, not the code. Press ALT+F12. Now you'll see the dfm content. Search for the ActionList component. Manually set Left and Top to 5. Press ALT+F12 again.